# py2app -- importing external modules

Tags: python, py2app, sys.path

Can `py2app` be set up such that the typical contents of a user's `sys.path` (when running python, not a py2app .app) are appended at the end of the path that py2app sets up?

I am bundling an application with an interactive python prompt -- I would like other users to be able to use modules they have built, but which are not provided in the main .app. If they try to import something that *is* bundled with `py2app`, I'd prefer that the `py2app` version be used.

The `--use-pythonpath` and `--site-packages` options to `py2app` don't seem to add all the directories that regular python does.

Comment: I think those options only work if you were to launch the executable from a terminal. Shell environment settings from the user wouldn't get passed when it is launched from the `.app`

Comment: I am launching the executable (dist/MyApplication.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApplication) from the terminal. It adds some, but not all, of the sys.path items I find when I launch python

Comment: The `sys.path` manipulation happens in the generated `__boot__.py` file, but the env variables it depends on are set up in the MyApplication wrapper executable. You can first hack up `__boot__.py` to print out what it's getting from the wrapper, then write the appropriate code to use that together with the user's normal path. But this sounds like a huge pain.

Comment: One quick question: This is a semi-standalone build, not a standalone, right? With a standalone build, you're not using the same Python as any of the user's existing installations, so you can't safely use their modules. With a semi-standalone build for, say, /usr/bin/python2.7, you should be able to.

Comment: It's a standalone build. However, my understanding is that any python executable from a fixed version can import and use a module, regardless of which executable it was installed with